# How to get data from a form which is written in inner HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

This is my code, here I want to access data from the textfields, how can I access them

This is my javascript function to add new form eevrytime add button is clicked

```
 function elementAppender() {
        if (count <= 5) {
            let element = document.createElement('div');
            element.id = `${count}`
```

Here, the code from which I have to get data is written in inner html

```
            element.innerHTML = `<div class="col-md-6 mx-auto my-5" id="myDiv">
                <div class="kumite-form">
                <button type="button" class="close col-md-2" data-dismiss="form" style="color: coral; float: right;" onclick="remdiv(), count-=1">&times;</button>
                    <form action="#" class="mx-auto">
                        <h3 style="text-align: left;margin-left:10%">Group ${count}</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    Category:
                                    <input class="" type="radio" name="category" value="female" style="font-size: 0.5px;">
                                    <label>Male</label>
                                    <input class="" type="radio" name="category" value="male" style="font-size: 0.5px;">
                                    <label>Female</label>
                                </div>
                            </li>


                            <h4 style="text-align: left;margin-left:10%">Player 1</h4>
                            <li><input type="text" placeholder="Player 1 Name"></li>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" onfocus="(this.type='date')"
                                onblur="(this.type='text')">
                            <li><input type="Number" placeholder="Weight (in kg)"></li>
```

Comment: Hi, input / option elements have a value attribute which can be used to retrieve what the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

The "value" property in JS comes in handy.

```
var myInput = document.querySelector("#idOfField").value
```